# EF Code First didn't create foreign key when it should have

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

Currently i'm following [Programming Entity Framework: Code First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312942), where the author created these model classes :

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Destination
    {
        public int DestinationID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lodging
    {
        public int LodgingID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public bool IsResort { get; set; }
        public Destination Destination { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And showed that the automatically generated database had a **foreign key** called `Destination_DestinationID` inside the `Lodgings` table. But the problem is in my case it's created as a normal **int** not a foreign key.

I'm using EF5 and i guess the book uses EF4.1, is this the cause of that difference ?

Comment: How are you checking whether it's a foreign key or not?

Comment: +1 to @qujck.  Why do you think Destination_DestinationID is not a FK?

Comment: From the Server explorer inside VS. I open the table columns and get the properties of the `Destination_DestinationID` column. It says **int** in the Data Type. Besides, its icon looks like the rest of the columns, not a key.

Comment: @RafaelAdel - You're referring to a Primary key, not a foreign key.

Comment: Right click the table and select 'open table definition'. Check the bottom of the SQL and you should see CONSTRAINT ...

Comment: I think you're worrying about nothing.  You're fine

Comment: Hmm that's strange. When i checked inside the management studio, i found that it's a foreign key, but inside VS server explorer it's shown as a normal int column.

Comment: @qujck Actually it's showed correctly inside the SQL Server Object Explorer not the  Server Explorer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the code and i am using EF Code First 5 and the generated Destination_DestinationId is indeed a foreign key. The problem isn't with code first but with Visual Studio Server explorer which doesn't show you that, i prefer to use SQL Server Management Studio for database related tasks and it will show you that the column is actually a foreign key with grey key icon.